# Phaser: how to group polygons in layers?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to have two polygons, one stationary and one that moves and changes its shape. When they overlap, I want the stationary polygon to stay in top.

This is my approach:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var SIZE_X = 400;
  var SIZE_Y = 300;
  var CENTER_COLOR = 0xFF33FF;
  var ALT_COLOR = 0xFFFF33;

  var moving_graphics;
  var tick = 0;

  var LayerTest = {
    preload: function() {},
    create: function() {
      game.world.setBounds(-SIZE_X / 2, -SIZE_Y / 2, SIZE_X / 2, SIZE_Y / 2);

      var center_group = game.add.group();
      center_group.z = 1;
      var center_graphics = new Phaser.Graphics(game, 0, 0);
      center_graphics.beginFill(CENTER_COLOR);
      center_graphics.drawPolygon(new Phaser.Polygon([
        new Phaser.Point(-30, -30),
        new Phaser.Point(-30, 30),
        new Phaser.Point(30, 30),
        new Phaser.Point(30, -30)
      ]));
      center_graphics.endFill();
      center_group.add(center_graphics);

      var moving_group = game.add.group();
      moving_group.z = 0;
      moving_graphics = new Phaser.Graphics(game, 0, 0);
      moving_group.add(moving_graphics);
    },
    update: function() {
      moving_graphics.clear();
      moving_graphics.beginFill(ALT_COLOR);
      moving_graphics.drawPolygon(new Phaser.Polygon([
        new Phaser.Point(-SIZE_X / 2 + tick - tick % 40, -10),
        new Phaser.Point(-SIZE_X / 2 + tick - tick % 40, 10),
        new Phaser.Point(20 - SIZE_X / 2 + tick, 10),
        new Phaser.Point(20 - SIZE_X / 2 + tick, -10)
      ]));
      moving_graphics.endFill();
      tick++;
    }
  };

  var game = new Phaser.Game(SIZE_X, SIZE_Y, Phaser.AUTO, '', LayerTest);
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm creating a pink square in the center and then a yellow rectangle that starts in the left side of the screen and then moves towards the center. However, even though I've added them to groups and the center one has a higher z-index, the moving group is always set on top. If I don't use groups and set the z-index directly for each graphics object, the final result is the same.

I want the moving group (the yellow rectangle) to remain behind the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the moving group before you add the center group.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var SIZE_X = 400;
  var SIZE_Y = 300;
  var CENTER_COLOR = 0xFF33FF;
  var ALT_COLOR = 0xFFFF33;

  var moving_graphics;
  var tick = 0;

  var LayerTest = {
    preload: function() {},
    create: function() {
      game.world.setBounds(-SIZE_X / 2, -SIZE_Y / 2, SIZE_X / 2, SIZE_Y / 2);

      var moving_group = game.add.group();
      moving_graphics = new Phaser.Graphics(game, 0, 0);
      moving_group.add(moving_graphics);
      
      var center_group = game.add.group();
      var center_graphics = new Phaser.Graphics(game, 0, 0);
      center_graphics.beginFill(CENTER_COLOR);
      center_graphics.drawPolygon(new Phaser.Polygon([
        new Phaser.Point(-30, -30),
        new Phaser.Point(-30, 30),
        new Phaser.Point(30, 30),
        new Phaser.Point(30, -30)
      ]));
      center_graphics.endFill();
      center_group.add(center_graphics);

    },
    update: function() {
      moving_graphics.clear();
      moving_graphics.beginFill(ALT_COLOR);
      moving_graphics.drawPolygon(new Phaser.Polygon([
        new Phaser.Point(-SIZE_X / 2 + tick - tick % 40, -10),
        new Phaser.Point(-SIZE_X / 2 + tick - tick % 40, 10),
        new Phaser.Point(20 - SIZE_X / 2 + tick, 10),
        new Phaser.Point(20 - SIZE_X / 2 + tick, -10)
      ]));
      moving_graphics.endFill();
      tick++;
    }
  };

  var game = new Phaser.Game(SIZE_X, SIZE_Y, Phaser.AUTO, '', LayerTest);
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So simple and I hadn't thought of this. Thank you!